# No "Choose OS" screen after co-installation of Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, windows

I don't have any technical knowledge of Ubuntu but wanted to install it on a partition.
Step-by-step of what i did.

1. used disk management in windows 7 to clear 50gb of space
2. used a usb live ubuntu 12.04 installer in custom install mode
3. used the installer's built in disk manager to set up 2gb swap space and 48gb ext4 space
4. ran installation, with option to copy over documents and settings from windows 7
5. restarted after completion.

After this, my computer automatically loads ubuntu 12 and skips the option to load windows 7. i know the files are still there, as i can see them in the file manager.
When trying to fix with the win7 installer dvd it tries to repair the OS in drive [D:] i.e. it recognises the disc itself as the OS and ignores the [c:] files.

I think, after browsing around here, similar problems suggest this is a problem with the boot loader, but if the win7 dvd won't work, then i don't have any way to fix this. does anyone know of a way to force the computer to show a "choose OS" screen?

Comment: What happens when you hold the shift key after the exiting the BIOS? GRUB should show up and give you the ability to choose what to boot. You can configure GRUB by editing /etc/default/grub, here you can also make GRUB displaying the "choose os menu" at startup (should be default actually).

Comment: i tried using shift. it didn't help. also, how does one go about editing the grub file?

Comment: here is your solution. I was also facing same issue.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/341620/after-installing-ubuntu-boot-screen-no-cable-connection/341767#341767

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your boot manager of choice.

> If you want windows to manage the boot menu, it wouldn't recognize
>   Ubuntu directly without a 3rd party boot manager like ***easybcd***.
>   If you want Ubuntu to manager the boot menu, you need to load
>   ***grub2***.

<sup>Source: https://superuser.com/questions/392033/no-boot-menu-after-installing-ubuntu</sup>

Grub needs to be fixed (Re-Installed).  The link below shows you how to do just that.

Click here for a [step-by-step instructions for using Grub.](http://fitusv.wordpress.com/2010/01/04/fixing-reinstalling-grub-grub2/)

[Reinstall / Recover GRUB from Ubuntu live CD / USB](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/)

Comment: I don't think Leon wants to replace GRUB with the Windows Boot Manager, for some reason GRUB boots directly into Ubuntu instead of showing the menu.

Comment: fernmann is right. the problem is that grub completely ignore windows. i have tried using the "update grub" temrinal command and that didn't solve it.

Comment: I understand, I'm just giving him a option.

Comment: i had a look, mitch, but i have no idea what the step-by-step guide is saying. [sorry]

Comment: its telling you how to repair or re-install Grub, by using the live CD.

Comment: ok i tried what it said in the instructions but that didn't work. i used a usb installer, would that affect it?

Comment: I just updated the answer.  Take a look. :)

Comment: i've just realised something. when my pc starts up the screen goes blank and displays an error message saying something about 58Hz. i think the boot screen is possibly not being shown. are there any keyboard commands for using it? this still happens even after having used boot-repair

Comment: What VGA are you using?

Comment: it's a GeForce 6150SE nForce 430. i happen to know that it's not a very good one.

Comment: actually, i have re-tried the boot-repair tool and selected to use a mbr instead of a grub. this allows me to access windows, but not ubuntu. i reckon this means that the problem _is_ the grub simply not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:

1. Your harddrive needs to be in MBR format, also Disable UEFI on laptop bios. Since, 12.04 Grub 1.99 wont know how to write BOOT FILE in this mode.
2. I formated my HDD from GPT to MBR with help of MiniTool Partition Wizard 7 Bootable USB.
3. Start installation again, sda1 ext4 partition with 100GB. path: /
4. Swap base: 4296MB
5. Rest space formated with ext4, PATH: /home

In case, you face BCM-kernal-source issue for make ur wireless card NOT working do the following in **terminal** after successful installation. Plug in Ethernet wired connection and below in terminal;

```
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```