# After installing Ubuntu Boot screen NO CABLE CONNECTION!

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot

I was using Windows 7.

Later, using USB bootable Ubuntu I installed Ubuntu on newly created NEW PARTITION TABLE.

Ext4 format.
sda1 - Ubuntu /
sda2 - Swap base
sda3 - Logical drive /data
sd4 - Logical drive /backup

After installation is complete, when I remove my USB drive and restart the machine.

I see this error on Boot screen.

> Intel UNDI PXE 2.0
>   ...
>   Check cable connection!

After that screen, it shows me F12 menu, if I select any of them same thing again.

But if I try to install Ubuntu again,it works. But after installation same issue again.

I have now converted my HDD to **MBR** with Partition Wizard Bootable USB.
Problem persists, even after installing again.

**My Laptop specs:**

Lenovo G580
Intel i5
4GB RAM
500GB HDD
Intel 4000HD gfx

Comment: I formatted my drive with "Mi niTool Partition Wizard Home Edition Bootable USB".

And then I installed Ubuntu again. But after installation and restarting I get the same error on BIOS. "Check cable connection!"

I think its not able to find Grub device.map ?? How do I add it manually ?

Comment: How to converted from GPT to MBR, since I have no OS installed

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the *edit* button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Boot the live cd, download and run this script, and edit the results into your question: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

1. Your harddrive needs to be in MBR format, also Disable UEFI on laptop bios. Since, 12.04 Grub 1.99 wont know how to write BOOT FILE in this mode.
2. I formated my HDD from GPT to MBR with help of MiniTool Partition Wizard 7 Bootable USB.
3. Start installation again, sda1 ext4 partition with 100GB. path: /
4. Swap base: 4296MB
5. Rest space formated with ext4, PATH: /home

If you face bcmwl-kernel-source issue preventing your wireless card from working do the following in **terminal** after successful installation. Plug in Ethernet wired connection and below in terminal;

```
wget http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/b/bcmwl/bcmwl-kernel-source_6.20.155.1+bdcom-0ubuntu6_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i bcmwl*.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the boot loader has been installed on the USB. Does the system boot up if you leave the USB drive plugged in after install and reboot?

If so, try installing with the default partitioning (you can always repartition later) or make sure to choose the correct device for boot loader when creating the partitioning.

Comment: With USB drive plugged in, it boots to bootloader screen. Where I can choose. 1. Try Ubuntu, 2. Install Ubunto, 3.Disk check for any errors.

Comment: I have re-installed today 7 times, with new PARTITION TABLE.
If I boot with USB only without installing Ubuntu. And Run Grub 2 config. I see it doesnt find sda1 > device.map

Comment: UPDATE: Im using MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Ed BOOTABLE USB to format whole disk. and gonna re-install Ubuntu.